# Does Assetic allow you to never publish resources?

Tags: symfony, assets

Symfony2 features Assetic, which appears to be a kind of asset pre-processor.  It has the ability to load assets from any path.

Right now, Symfony2 requires that you "publish" assets from your bundles which to me seems unwieldy.

Is it possible or a good idea to totally sidestep having to publish assets by having your controllers and templates prepare everything via Assetic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's good to use Assetic to prepare your resources (maybe do some minification or similar). But as far as I know, Assetic also requires you to "publish" (e.g. "dump") your assets. This is done using the "assetic:dump" command.

You can also run Assetic in debug-mode, having it checking for changes in your assets (--watch) and then dumping them.

For me the assets "publishing" haven't been that much of work, since I add the --symlink flag to the "assets:install" command when I run it. This creates symlinks for each web/bundles/bundlename-folder, referencing to the bundles/MyCompany/MyBundle/Resources/public-folder.

The only situation where I have to re-run the publishing command is when adding new bundles (or when adding a public folder to any of my own bundles).

I hope this answers your question. If not, please add some additional comments on what you feel is unwieldy and how you would like Symfony2 to behave :)

UPDATE 2012-01-23
Since your last comment I've been working some more with Symfony2. Yesterday I had an idea - perhaps you can register your own Twig function to handle the assets, and then use something like Synfony2's FileLocator to find the files (which you then pass to Assetic)?
Maybe not the best way to handle assets, but a solution that is more compliant with your request, at least :-)

Comment: I would like assetic to follow the same type of hierarchy that symfony config files do i.e. if I'm calling the `asset()` helper from within a particular bundle, search for the asset within that bundle's `public` dir first. If you don't find it in there, then look for it in the root `web` dir.

Comment: Added a section to my answer. If you've already solved this, feel free to share how you did it :-)